# Oracle - initialising a variable that is a user-defined type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm attempting to use pipelined functions in Oracle. I've declared my type like so:

```
create or replace type t_my_row as object (
  ID                        NUMBER(19),
  STATUS                    CHAR(4),
  DATE_CREATED              VARCHAR2(9),
  FIELD1                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD2                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD3                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD4                    VARCHAR2(3)
);
```

In my function I am looping round a cursor and loading the results into a variable of the type above before returning using pipe_row().

All works OK but I think there must be an easier way to initialise the variable that I am loading into. I am doing it like this:

```
v_my_row t_my_row := t_my_row(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

In reality there are 35 parameters which makes the code look very ugly - so my question is, is there a better way of initialising a user-defined variable than this in Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a constructor:

```
create or replace type t_my_row as object 
(
  ID                        NUMBER(19),
  STATUS                    CHAR(4),
  DATE_CREATED              VARCHAR2(9),
  FIELD1                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD2                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD3                    VARCHAR2(3),
  FIELD4                    VARCHAR2(3),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_my_row(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_my_row)
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

CREATE TYPE BODY t_my_row AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_my_row(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_my_row) 
                               RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
        self.id := null;
        self.status := null;
        self.date_created := null;
        self.field1 := null;
        self.field2 := null;
        self.field3 := null;
        self.field4 := null;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

Then in your PL/SQL code, you can use it like this:

```
v_my_row t_my_row := t_my_row();
```